# Typescript: use `this` type inside a class constructor

Tags: typescript, class, typescript-class

I have the following class with a constructor that defines properties on it. I need the constructor to accept an object which only contains the (extending) class members

```js
abstract class A {
    constructor(initializer: Partial<this>) { // <-- using this type in a constructor is not allowed!
        for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(initializer)) {
            Object.defineProperty(this, key, { value, enumerable: true })
        }
    }
    static someStaticMethod() {}
    someInstancemethod() {}
    
}
```

this class is only used to be extended by other classes

```js
class B extends A {
    a?: string
    b?: number
    c?: boolean
}

new B({ a: "hello", b: 1, c: true, d: "this must error" }) // <-- I want only properties of B here in the constructor argument
```

I know I can add a type argument to `A` and then assign the extending class to it

```js
abstract class A<T> {
    constructor(initializer: Partial<T>) {
        ...
    }
}

class B extends A<B> {
...
}
```

But this solution of repeating `B` doesn't look elegant, especially considering that this is an external API for a library I'm working on. Is it possible to achieve what I want, leaving the syntax as in the first example: `class B extends A`? If not, what is a possible workaround?
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gWACgFikB7AO0igFd5SoAKAS3KYieGSYC8BTKAFwIACsCjtOAHggALJmAB8ASlyES6hADN6CBrAqQEAbQDWvAJ4AaAG6dqvALoJSmhAHkQAK17wAdL3JoJl4wZlYJLj4oJRV8Ig0Ej28-ABNeTRZeYShSAAd+CHMGWXlLBDMrXARbZHsygOoAW35QZF4haHsEAF8lNQSe-uJuoYRIYHZYMdJmgGUICaZYAFleWVIUhliR+OIwGd4ASUoF8lheZvXN7dHCHcIUNAwAIQReAA8IAJSMbDj1YAAfiEVBYAHNRiBgQhyE0QPxRrBoSBSKQ2sByHdCA8DGjeL5kKQwQxyLwAO4IZ4MHAIYBCABEMl4yEJ9LKICEAEYyrAOjReGUUgyShhGtRDPwclB6T0YkA)

Comment: Repeating `B` as a generic argument is a pretty standard pattern called the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). I'll agree that it's not the most elegant solution, but it is pretty standard.

Comment: No, this is not possible.  There is a request at [ms/TS#38038](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38038) to support something like this, and if you want you can go there and give it a  and describe your use case, but it's not part of the language now and might not be ever.  Are you interested in other workarounds (if so you should [edit] the question to specify this)?  Or do you just want an answer that says "no" with documentation?  Let me know (and mention me with @jcalz if you reply so I am notified)

Comment: ...hmm, how do you plan `private` to work in your subclasses?  `Partial<B>` has no access to the `a`, `b`, or `c` properties.  When you write "I know I can add a type argument to `A` and then assign the extending class to it", have you tried that?  It's impossible to pass in `a`, `b`, or `c` there.  Could you fix this in your question so there's only one stumbling block and not multiple?

Comment: Thanks.  Does [this workaround](https://tsplay.dev/wXj0Qm) work for you?  You can emulate `this` in static methods, but not in the constructor itself.  If this addresses your question I can write up an answer explaining it with relevant documentation.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: thank you @jcalz, this answers my question. I would appreciate it if you could include some hint about *why* this isn't supported by ts in your answer

Comment: How could I answer "why" it's not supported authoritatively, other than pointing to ms/TS#38038 and shrugging?  I can *guess* that it wasn't implemented because the constructor is in the unique position of being a static method whose `this` context is that of an instance instead of the constructor itself, so to support it would have required some conscious effort, and it hasn't happened.  That's just a guess though.  Unless there's a documented reason for why this isn't already supported I wouldn't know how to answer.  It also seems a bit out of scope of the question as asked.

Comment: I guess your *guess* is enough, I thought there was some more documented reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible in TypeScript to use [`this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) in the call signature for [a class `constructor()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor).  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#38038](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38038) asking for such support, but for now it's not part of the language.

(A comment asked why it isn't already supported, but I don't have an authoritative answer for that.  I can guess: The `constructor` method is unique in that it is a static method whose `this` context is that of a class instance, so presumably implementing `this` typing for its call signature would have required some conscious effort to do.  And it's not a feature the community is clamoring for, as evidenced by the relatively few upvotes on the issue linked above.  Those are probably contributing factors for why it is not already supported.  But, as I said, these are guesses.)

---

Until and unless that is implemented you'd need to use workarounds.

One such workaround would be to use [a `static` method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#static-members) with `this` types instead of the constructor, so you call `B.make({})` instead of `new B({})`.

Unfortunately `this` types are also not supported for static methods.  Support is requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863).  But you can *simulate* such behavior with [`this` parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) and a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, as mentioned [in this comment on that GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-242782664):

```
abstract class A {
    static make<T extends A>(
      this: new (initializer: Partial<A>) => T, 
      initializer: Partial<T>
    ) {
        return new this(initializer);
    }
    constructor(initializer: Partial<A>) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(initializer)) {
            Object.defineProperty(this, key, { value, enumerable: true })
        }
    }
    static someStaticMethod() { }
    someInstancemethod() { }

}
```

The `make()` method can only be called on a concrete constructor which accepts a `Partial<A>` and produces an instance of type `T` constrained to `A`.  So you can't call `A.make()` directly for the same reason you can't call `new A()`, since the constructor is abstract:

```
A.make({}) // error!
// <-- Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type
```

But you can subclass as desired, and the static `make()` method will be inherited:

```
class B extends A {
    a?: string
    b?: number
    c?: boolean
}
```

When you call `B.make()`, then, the compiler infers that `T` is `B` and so the parameter to `make()` is `Partial<B>`, which, among other things, will reject [excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks):

```
const b = B.make({ a: "hello", b: 1, c: true }); // okay
// const b: B
console.log(b); // {a: "hello", b: 1, c: true}

B.make({ a: "hello", b: 1, c: true, d: "this must error" }); // error!
// -------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Object literal may only specify known properties
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gWAChCESFJgIBLWBAW2AGsBTAHgBUEmAPCJgOwAmGTAD4AFBAAWlMAC4EfJgHcEYyn0pVgySgC8mUeQAVgULchaiAlAgC8IhGwA0CdZsra9B46fPsRNvgEpCEIUEwQAK5QfArKCFIyahrmXlBWANzEpAC+hNkksAD2fJBQkfBFUMnunvqGCCZmHhbWuAWhAGZVqsWliADazACeLgBu2pFMALoIRZ0IAPIgAFZM8AB0-NCUTGA1qfVWgR2hpMtrmwJMnepMRlBFAA4GEMMS0mAuIy44CBPIKYufiRWgGUDIJjyaBTBA5KynXIdPLBUjkKg0MBFMEAZQgFGoAFkIpIigIxIE4R0sWCAJL9YB8WBMMFSMkU3BUogEFGETAbejMMQ4eEIAD0Ys4UEeUAAhIQJQgWABaZUIADCjL4RUQaDAlAA5rFGQhQGU4Ig+mUKhAem8XgkiqaFCVlWboBakCVrZUoAlhi98tyUHqEAAhTg8fhCLDtVEkYAAfnkZXUBo6IGTClBIAMHVgWZARSKkMZhF5we9iBAdnDAsYTGFpvkACJJExkMgii2XCB5ABGFywaHlJhwzLiyVFBjAYYKyVW6vyMOEK0lpgbLsGsQgCeKnDAVvtzvd3sDocjqYVsP1oV-Q8INsdrs9hB9hCDpCXpguAStxIYLQkSQFKMotuOGSTqBVTygQiqqghiFIchKGIQ4AB+mFYdhOE4fOSyrOsiA6LwMDIHQs5zHwyDDGQLywJQnS0Qw2pKLETyPC8zR7EAA)